# Ruby on rails3 where to put javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty much a novice to the world of Ruby on Rails, a few weeks back I followed Lynda's good ruby on rails guide so I kinda know how to set up a project etc. Anyway, I made an website in html/css but wanted to do it in rails after all so I went to work. I love how you can just "dump" files in folders and rails just picks them out but I also had a few lines of javascript code on my site to "activate" the jquery following. It was in my header

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
    $(function(){

    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: false,
    autoReinitialise: true
        });

});
</script>
```

So the simple question now is, where do I put this code since rails doesn't really have an .

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page for layout and rendering: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

There is a section there about rendering your ERB templates. You need to put your javascript code in your .erb template, within the head, just like you would in a normal HTML page.

To be clear, you can save the contents of your script tag into a .js file and link to it in your template, just like you would in plain HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your JS:

- in the erb template it deals with
- under public/javscripts in a normal .js file that you can include in templates using the javascript_include_tag helper
- in seperate .js.erb template files for ajaxian / manual include purposes

**EDITED**, per suggestion:

Personally, I'd choose one of the last 2 since those are more Convention over Configuration, or the "Rails" way, which is what I believe you're looking for.

Comment: Well, you may as well explain your last sentence. Voodoo programming comes out of statements like that.

Comment: Well I tried putting the code in a "jquery_slider.js" file in the public/javascript folder but it does not seem to help. So I am going to try your first option, but like Jordan said I would like to know what's bad about it.

Comment: See @Nick's response for the include tag that works as a test. But then change the include to <%= javascript_include_tag :name_of_js_file %>. The first choice I gave is bad because it's just like including javascript directly in HTML files. Combining HTML / javascript / css in the same file creates hard-to-manage projects.

Comment: @dmf85: I understand where you're going now. Certainly you would want to link out to an external file if this is supposed to be reused. I don't see anything like that specified in point #1 (meaning, it could just be a `<script src="...">`), so I was curious why you wouldn't just do that. For me, I would combine your point #1 and #2 and say that's the correct way of linking an external script.

Comment: I put the website up on Heroku so maybe you guys can take a look,
http://morning-spring-991.heroku.com/home/index

and this is the non rails site
http://no-illusions.nl/keepmewaiting/

As you can see the non rails version has the blue scrollbar, all the js code is being loaded but it does not seem to work. I think it's because this code

<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
    $(function(){

    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: false,
    autoReinitialise: true
        });

});
</script type="text/javascript">

should be placed in the header instead of an JS file.

Comment: @Jordan I see where the confusion could arise. I apologize for the ambiguity.

Comment: @alucardu, are you using firebug to debug the Net requests to verify the URL of the javascript the app is looking for? If not, I recommend doing that and using the net tab and the HTML tab to debug that local issue.

Answer (score 0):

I put all scripts in public/javascripts in a directory structure that mirrors controller/action names + a vendor directory and a common directory. In my application.html.* I have code to load what I need for the controller/action into the header. I make a strong effort to not put javascript into my .haml (.erb) files but am willing to break that rule if I must.

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in `public/javascripts/` until Rails 3.1.

Also make sure you are including your javascripts in the template.

```
<% javascript_include_tag :all %>
```

Comment: Doesn't Rails automatically put all the js files from that folder in the header?

Comment: No. It will only if you add `<% javascript_include_tag :all %>` to the `<head></head>` block in the application template file.

Answer (score 0):

For loading reasons, don't you want certain javascript snippets to be called after the template loads rather than in the beginning (ex: called in the header)?